When type checking, how to make a pydantic model attribute accept multiple input types for a custom Class without overloading every model?
I'm using the Pydantic library, version 2.
I have created a custom class that subclasses int and implements a __get_pydantic_core_schema__ method.
When using this custom class in a Pydantic model, I want the type checker (Basedpyright) to understand that the attribute of the instantiated model will be only of the type of my custom class (MyCustomInt), but also that I can instantiate the model with a str or an int (or MyCustomInt itself).
However, I don't want to define overloads or override the __init__ method on every model that uses my custom class, as it defeats the purpose and makes the code very verbose, especially if I need to redefine all attributes in every __init__ overload/override.
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
from typing import Any, reveal_type
from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema
from pydantic import GetCoreSchemaHandler, BaseModel

class MyCustomInt(int):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
            cls,
            _source_type: Any,
            _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    ) -> CoreSchema:
        def validate_from_int(value: int) -> "MyCustomInt":
            if value < 0:
                raise ValueError("Cannot be negative")
            return cls(value)

        from_int_schema = core_schema.chain_schema(
            [
                core_schema.int_schema(),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(validate_from_int),
            ]
        )

        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=from_int_schema,
            python_schema=core_schema.union_schema(
                [
                    core_schema.is_instance_schema(cls),
                    from_int_schema,
                ]
            ),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(
                str,
                return_schema=core_schema.str_schema(),
                when_used='json'
            ),
        )

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    value: MyCustomInt

model = MyModel(value="123")  # Error: Argument of type "str" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "MyCustomInt" in function "__init__"
reveal_type(model.value)  # Revealed type is 'MyCustomInt' - Good!
model = MyModel(value=123)  # Error: Argument of type "int" cannot be assigned to parameter "value" of type "MyCustomInt" in function "__init__"
reveal_type(model.value)  # Revealed type is 'MyCustomInt' - Good!

To be clear, this works perfectly fine at runtime, and this is purely a type-checking issue.
Is there a way to inform the type checker about the acceptable validation types for MyCustomInt without having to overload or override __init__ in every model?

Try:
from typing import Union
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    value: Union[MyCustomInt, int, str]

From official Python docs:

Union type; Union[X, Y] is equivalent to X | Y and means either X or
Y.
To define a union, use e.g. Union[int, str] or the shorthand int |
str.

By declaring the value as Union[MyCustomInt, int, str], the type checker understands that the value can be initialized with any of these types.
